# Upload multiple images with asynchronous process

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I'm trying to upload images from ajax request. In action I have to save 4 different sizes for that images.

I want to save only one in current thread, and rest 3 image image in another thread, so that user don't have to wait for upload all images, As I only required the path of first Image.

This is what I have done so far.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadImage(bool isUploadLogo = false)
{
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
        if (file != null)
        {
           var getExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
           var getBytesArray = ResizeImage.ConvertToByte(file);
            string fileName = "TestImage" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + getExt;
            var smallSizeImageBytes = ResizeImage.ResizeImageBytes(200, 200, getBytesArray, getImageFormat);
            var pic = ImageStore.UploadImage(fileName, file.ContentType, smallSizeImageBytes);

            //Save Slider Image,  Without Wait
            if (!isUploadLogo)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    UploadSliderImage(getBytesArray);
                }).Start();
            }
            var result = new
            {
                url = "Folder Path Here" + fileName,        
                isSuccess = "true"
            };
            return Json(result, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}

public void UploadSliderImage(byte[] CroppedImage)
{
    //Code for upload diffrent size images
}
```

Although I'm calling **UploadSliderImage** inside another thread, But In client side I'm not getting the result until **UploadSliderImage** process complete.

How can I return the data to client side without waiting for uploading remaining images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better for you to use Task instead of the Thread class assuming you are using .net 4.0 and above. Here is a sample code that you can base on. It will return the Json Immediately without finishing the Task.

```
        Debug.WriteLine("Image Upload");

        Task tsk = new Task(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000); //This is your UploadSlider Image
            Debug.WriteLine("Done");

        });
        tsk.Start();

        return Json("result", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: It doesn't effecting total time elapsed. I'm checking it in browser console. Earlier It was taking around 800ms and still It is taking the same time. Which Is equal to total time to upload image without using `Task`

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Return Json will be called first before the Debug.WriteLine("Done");

Comment: Yes. you are right. `return` statement is getting called before `Debug.Writeline`. But Don't know why It is taking same time.

Comment: Then that answers your question. I'm not sure with the time part but I think this solves your problem on (return the data to client side without waiting for uploading remaining images)